# "Index.php?webpage" Not Functioning properly

Tags: php, post, get, isset

So I am trying to access a certain webpage within my site.

In my index, I use a isset($_GET() parameter to access another page. My code for the index.php is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php require ("includes/database.php"); ?>
    <title>Offstreams Admin Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/admin_body.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/admin_header.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/admin_footer.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/admin_postspace.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <!--Header Info Here -->
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php?post_new_band">Post New Band</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <article>
            <?php
                if (isset($_GET['post_new_band'])){
                    require ("includes/post_new_band.php");

                    echo "Page accessed";
                } else {
                    echo "Page not accessible."; 
                }       
            ?>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have it echo page not available when "index.php?page" doesn't exist. But when it does exist, such as "index.php?post_new_band" (code below) nothing is posted. The sever and database work, that is for sure. MySQL isn't the problem since I am trying to get the html to work.

Code for "post_new_band.php":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Head Info Goes Here -->
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Insert New Band</h1>
       <form action='index.php?post_new_band' method='post'>
           <b>Insert New Band</b><input type='text' name='band_name' />
           <b>Insert Band Origin</b><input type='text' name='band_origin' />
           <input type='submit' name='insert_band' value='Add Band' />
       </form>

   <?php
       if (isset($_POST['post_new_band'])){
           $band_name = $_POST['band_name'];

           if($band_name==''){
               echo "<script>alert ('Please Insert Band Name')</script>";
               echo "<script>window.open('index.php?post_new_band','_self')</script>"
           } else {

               $insert_band_name = "insert into Band  (band_name) values ('$band_name')";

               $run_band_name = mysql_query("$insert_band_name");

               echo "<script>alert ('New Category Added')</script>";
               echo "<script>window.open('index.php?post_new_band','_self')</script>"
           }
       }
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use a request key once - so dont use `$_GET['post_new_band']` and `$_POST['post_new_band']` in the same request. Change one of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty stupid, but it actually turned out to be a syntax error involving semi-colons. *Slap to the face.